# cant connect to docker private registry "getsockopt: no route to host"

Tags: docker, nexus3

I created a docker private registry on nexus3 (dockerized).

when im trying to log in using: "docker login -u admin -p admin123 myIP:8213"

i get the following message: "Error response from daemon: Get https://myIP:8213/v2/: dial tcp myIP:8213: getsockopt: no route to host

i created nexus3 container with port 8213 exposed.

can anybody help?

TNX

Comment: have you checked your firewall ? can you check with telnet myIp 8213 to see if you can reach there ?

Comment: i tried but nothing comes up,
making things clear
im using a centos dist and i started a nexus container on that machine, now host and container IP is the same. but telnet returns "unknown host".

Comment: Can you show the docker-compose file if you have one? Or the way that you're running the container.

Comment: solved, 
the problem was that I addressed the docker private registry with the real IP, while all of my containers were on the same host, so addressing the docker private registry with 127.0.0.1:8213 was the right way to do so.